# How to create new Sails model from an existing model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, data-modeling, waterline

I am new to Sails and creating a simple application.
I am stuck with data model now.
`User` model is as follows:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    firstName: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: 'String'
    },
    passwordSalt: {
     type: 'String'
    },
    projects:{
     collection: 'ProjectMember',
     via: 'userId'
    }
  }
};
```

I need one more Model called `TinyUser` which gets some of attributes from User (Like Foreign key to User), so that I can access `TinyUser` instead of accessing `User` directly.
TinyUser Model is as follows:

```
module.exports = {  
 tableName: 'User',  
  attributes: {  
    firstName:{  
     type: 'string'  
    },  
    lastName: {  
      type: 'string'
  },
  email: {
      type: 'email'
  }  
}  
};
```

ProjectMember model is as follows:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

    projectId: {
        model: 'Project'
    },
    userId: {
        model: 'TinyUser'
    },
    projectRole: {
        model: 'ProjectRole'
    },

}  
};
```

In Sails, Is there anyway I can save data in `TinyUser` without actually creating but just holding some of attributes of User table data?

To Make it clear, If there is another table called Task and it is trying to access user data then TinyUser is better option as a model rather than User as it holds only required info. for task rather than storing all other fields which User does.

Is there any way I can fix this?
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you need to have the "TinyUser" inherited from the "User" model?

You can do it like this.

/api/services/baseUserModel.js:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    },
    password: 'string',
    passwordSalt: 'string',
    projects: {
      collection: 'ProjectMember',
      via: 'userId'
    }
  }
};
```

/api/models/TinyUser.js:

```js
var baseUserModel = require('../services/baseUserModel'),
  _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = _.merge({
  tableName: 'User',
  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    }
  }
}, baseUserModel);
```

And the ProjectMember model should be:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    projectId: {
      model: 'project'
    },
    userId: {
      model: 'tinyuser'
    },
    projectRole: {
      model: 'projectrole'
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: I got following error on trying this: 
Error: Trying to associate a collection attribute to a model that doesn't have a Foreign Key. tinyuser is trying to reference a foreign key in projectmember at References.findReference ....

Any idea why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the "ProjectMember" model, one thing you should pay attention to is that inside the "ProjectMember.js", the associated attribute should be like this : `userid: {model: 'tinyuser'},`. Please reference to the [official doc](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html)

Comment: I have updated my question with ProjectMember Model, Error is still same, user is trying to reference a foreign key in project member.

Comment: I've also updated my answer, please try to change the reference model name with **lowercase**

Comment: I tried with lowercase, but still it did not work. I found this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/5YSR0qfyLFU which tells that inheritance does not work in Sails .10.x. Are you using Sails 10.x?